# .contextMenu is adding a background color where it's not supposed to

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-contextmenu

I have a Message View built from an avatar and a message bubble, I want to add a .contextMenu to popup when pressing on the bubble and it should highlight the bubble and avatar. The problem is that the context menu is adding a whiteish background color between the avatar and bubble, when i wanted to be transparent.

[image]

How it should be

[image]

Here is my code:

```
struct MessageCellView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: MessageCellViewModel

var body: some View {
    HStack {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                avatar("avatar")
                bubble()
                    .cornerRadius(17, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight])
                    .cornerRadius(5, corners: [.bottomLeft])
            }
            .contextMenu {
                Button {
                    // Do somethind
                } label: {
                    if viewModel.isUserMuted {
                        Label("Unmute User", systemImage: "person.fill.checkmark")
                    } else {
                        Label("Mute User", systemImage: "person.fill.xmark")
                    }
                }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

private func bubble() -> some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(" name ")
            .foregroundStyle(Color.grey900)
            .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .semibold))
        Text(" Text ")
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular))
        Text("9m")
            .foregroundStyle(Color.grey700)
            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular))
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    .padding(.vertical, 6)
    .background(Color.grey100)
}

private func avatar(_ image: String) -> some View {
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: image)) { phase in
        switch phase {
        case .empty:
            ProgressView()
                .padding()
        case .success(let image):
            image.resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: 40, maxHeight: 40)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        case .failure:
            ProgressView()
                .padding()
        @unknown default:
            ProgressView()
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `.contentShape` for the `.contextMenuPreview` to the desired custom shape **BEFORE** the `contextMenu`, like:

```
.contentShape(ContentShapeKinds.contextMenuPreview, MessageMask())
.contextMenu { ,,, }
```

[image: Demo]

Here is an example of a mask you need based on your design:

```
struct MessageMask: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var message = Path()

        let circleR: CGFloat = 40
        let spacing: CGFloat = 10
        let largeCR: CGFloat = 17
        let smallCR: CGFloat = 5

        // Add a circle as the avatar
        message.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: rect.maxY - circleR, width: circleR, height: circleR))

        let leading = circleR + spacing
        message.move(to: CGPoint(x: leading, y: rect.maxY))

        // Add a custom rounded rectangle as the bubble
        message.addRoundedRect(
            in: CGRect(x: leading, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width - leading, height: rect.height),
            cornerRadii: .init(
                topLeading: largeCR,
                bottomLeading: smallCR,
                bottomTrailing: largeCR,
                topTrailing: largeCR
            )
        )

        return message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a closer look to the solution, it's not matching the message perfectly, it seems like the mask is being set a little under the center of the message, but at least I have a BIG clue of what to do!!! Thanks @Mojtaba Hosseini.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Yes I saw some issue in the original layout when I was trying to build it in a way to output the demo image I've attached. I didn't post more about it because it wasn't in the scope of this question.

Comment: Once I get it to work I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks! it's only masking the avatar but not the bubble

Comment: @JavierHeisecke does it work for you?

Comment: still no, the message is not being highlighted and if it was it would only be highlighted partly :(

Comment: The screenshot I've attached is directly from the code and as you can see, both parts are highlighted correctly. I suspect that you have issues out of the code you've sent here. Maybe you can upload a minimum project somewhere and let me commit on that.

Comment: I forgot I changed the HStack { } to a Group { }, Group was messing everything up, Thanks!!! it works perfectly.